# Redis ServiceStack TimeoutException C# Asp.Net

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack, pool, timeoutexception

When using ServiceStack.Redis, TimeoutException is thrown since all the pools are being used. How to resolve the timeout exception.

Answer (score 1):

#### Possible connection leak

The `TimeoutException` only happens when the pools are full, i.e. when there are no connections available which is usually an indication that you have a connection leak in which case make sure that all redis clients resolved from the pool are released, which you can ensure by wrapping each usage in a using statement, e.g:

```
using (var redis = redisManager.GetClient())
{
    //...
}
```

#### RedisManagerPool creates new connections instead when full

Another option to is to use the [RedisManagerPool](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redismanagerpool) which instead of throwing a `TimeoutException` will create a new connection outside the pool, however this will usually just mask the problem of a connection leak and it will result in a high open/closed connection count.

#### Increase Pool Resource Settings

If you believe the TimeoutException is due to heavy load you can increase the pool size and timeout seconds, e.g:

```
var redisManager = new PooledRedisClientManager(
    redisReadWriteHosts, redisReadOnlyHosts,
    poolSizeMultiplier: 40, //connection pool size * no of hosts
    poolTimeOutSeconds: 5); //how long to block for available connection
```

Comment: ClientManager is initialized using Sentinel like this

    `var objSentinel = new ServiceStack.Redis.RedisSentinel("127.0.0.1", "6379");`
`ServiceStack.Redis.IRedisClientsManager objClientManager = sentinel.Start();`

How to get PooledRedisClientManager from Sentinel